# Is there a python way to groupby the dataframe in the below way

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame that has the details of person1 and person2 which is obtained when they breach social distance. I have details such as timestamp. I want to groupby the data frame for each person for a date and for a particular hour. I have completed these steps. but the problem I am facing is, is there a way to extract the people with whom he contacted with the groupby method. I have written the below code:

```
df2_sd = df_2.groupby(['Date', 'Hour', 'username']).agg({'breach_count' : ['sum']})
```

Is there a better way to extract this information? i have attached sample data frame for reference (left: sample, right: result required)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can pass `','.join()`  to aggregate function

```
>>>df2_sd=df_2.groupby(['Date', 'Hour', 'username']).agg({'breach_count' : sum,'contact_name':','.join}).reset_index()
>>>print(df2_sd)
         Date  Hour username  breach_count contact_name
0  01-06-2020     1        A             3        X,X,Y
1  01-06-2020     2        A             1            X
2  01-06-2020     2        B             1            Y
3  01-06-2020     2        C             1            Z
4  01-06-2020     3        A             1            A
5  01-06-2020     3        B             1            A
6  01-06-2020     3        C             1            B
```